# $\iiint_R (x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{3}{2}e^{-x^2-y^2-z^2}dV_{xyz}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

im having trouble evaluating this triple integral

$\iiint_R (x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{3}{2}e^{-x^2-y^2-z^2}dV_{xyz}$

$R = (x,y,z):1\le x^2+y^2+z^2\le9$

any help is appreciated as always.

Comment: Have you considered a different coordinate system?

Comment: the one that comes to mind is spherical...? that means its a sphere with radius $\sqrt{z^2 + 9}$ ?

Comment: No, it is a sphere of radius 3 with a hole of radius 1 in its middle, all centered at the origin.

Comment: ok, so convert to spherical then integrate with respect to $r,\phi,\theta$ $r= 2...3, \phi,\theta = 0..2\pi$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Whenever you see $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$, this is begging to be transformed to $\rho^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ (spherical coordinates).

So, applying that substitution (and including the Jacobian):
$$\iiint_G (\rho^3e^{-\rho^2})\rho^2 \sin(\varphi)dV_{\rho,\varphi,\theta}$$

EDIT: For converting the region (as seems to be your questions from the comments), we can see that it's a sphere of radius $3$ with a hole of radius $1$ (as Ron Gordon noted).  To model this, we let $\rho$ range from $1$ to $3$, $\varphi$ from $0$ to $\pi$ and $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: Your answer was first!

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider a different coordinate system, a spherical one to be precise, noting $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$. This means we then express our domain in spherical coordinates as

$$R=\{(r,\theta,\phi)|1\le r^2\le9,0\le\theta\lt\pi,0\le\phi\lt2\pi\}$$

i.e. a closed ball of radius 3 with a spherical hole of radius 1 at its core, centered at the origin.

Recalling that $\mathrm{d}V=r^2\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi$, we may rewrite our integral as an iterated integral in spherical coordinates:

$$\begin{align*}\iiint\limits_{R}(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac32e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)}\mathrm{d}V&=\iiint\limits_{R}r^5e^{-r^2}\mathrm{d}V\\&=\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\phi\int_0^\pi\mathrm{d}\theta\sin\theta\int_1^3\mathrm{d}r\,r^5e^{-r^2}\end{align*}$$

Comment: thanks for this... i had just wrote down simular but i had 2-3 instead of 1-3, my mistake! thanks again!

Comment: @anorton great catch! Thanks :-)

Comment: @Neo I enjoy these problems quite a bit -- thanks for the practice. I take a multivariable calculus course this summer.